# Which group of events can cause global domination by a single country?

Tags: far-future

**Background:** The world is preferably a few hundred years in the future, and a single country (possibly one of our top powers,  but other minor countries can work within reason), Has absorbed every other country and is now the only country on the planet. Which event or group of events may cause this scenario?

- This scenario can be caused as an aftermath of a disaster, but the earth can not currently be in a dystopian scenario.
- This event can not be caused by any external non-natural influence (aliens no, asteriod yes)
- The event cannot severely change the layout or landmass of the planet (Florida can be where texas is and vice versa, but Florida can not suddenly be below south Africa)
- The effects of the event cannot be abrupt (as in, one day everybody suddenly made a world government), the effect has to be spread out over a period of at least 48 months (4 years)

Comment: Secret Service sabotages the economy polices of your enemy states, so you get total global economic domination...

Comment: I think you accepted a answer too fast.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! Your question is a bit too broad. It is possible to write several books each depicting a different chain of events resulting in your desired outcome. I doubt you can edit the question now to make it more focused without invalidating already posted answers, but in the future please try to ask more specific questions (as per [Help Centre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) guidelines).

Comment: This could be anything from "an asteroid strike wiped everyone else out" to "everyone else voluntarily joined a one world government"; we need more conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically there's two ways humans react to a catastrophe: they either turn against each other, or they unite. We've seen thousands of people attack one another out of fear of a global pandemic, but we've also seen whole nations come together after a devastating terrorist attack.

For your world to swear fealty to a single nation, I think it would have to be due to a set of falling dominoes that culminates into one major climax in order to get your people to unite rather than turn against each other, otherwise you're always going to have rebels, antagonists, and people who disagree with a global union. You have to get the masses to 1) be scared enough, and 2) believe that union is the only way to stay safe.

I'm going to reference the book of Revelation a bit for an example—in Revelation, the world comes together to form a global power shortly after all the Christians alive in the world suddenly vanish. We don't know just how many people disappear, but we can assume it would induce some kind of global panic. From airplane pilots to national leaders, this would be a major upset--a climatic catastrophe.

We see one of the elements of this global union is a Mark in the hand that allows everyone to buy and sell in the global market. Some people used to think it was a barcode, others a microchip, and more recently, a vaccine. Regardless of what it's supposed to be, you have an entire world voluntarily putting this "mark" in their bodies to be a part of society. Three years ago, this concept seemed a little far-fetched: now, it's a daily headline in the news. Vaccine mandates are seen across the globe, and if they become normalized, a future event that requires some "mark" will seem less extreme to many (I should insert that I'm not giving an opinion about current headlines, by the way...just using it as an example).

Little dominoes like this will prep your people for a global fusion, and it's best if these dominoes are connected to some kind of *uncontrollable* event like a pandemic or terrorist attack: in both the cases for COVID and 9/11, all political parties agreed *something* should be done in response...just not always agreeing on the *how*, but if the government just one day decided to--I dunno--force its people to all wear the color red from now on because it "unites them," you're going to have mostly pushback. Think of what you want your future nation to look like, then work backwards with little events here and there that normalize the leadership and culture. The little dominoes will likely cause mini wars, disagreements, rebels, and radicals...but if government or society can overcome them and then prove they were helpful, there will be more and more people who just come to accept them. Everything from TSA to seatbelt laws change culture, and many times there's public outcry that eventually goes silent.

Once your society is prepped, you need a world power with a strong leader and charismatic personality. Then you can drop the catastrophic climax on the world (like the Rapture in Revelation), and the terrified people will turn to someone who has answers and/or resources. I would make this person an economist/businessman/strategist/or even military...someone who really knows what it's like to organize people/numbers/funds, etc. I would also make him plugged in with other world powers or players in your planned union. Going back to Revelation, the global ruler is extremely popular and is able to not just get one country on board with his plan, but *everyone*. That means Israel, Palestine, Iran, North Korea, China, Russia, and Afghanistan are all willing to be peaceful buddies under this new ruler...that wouldn't happen unless the global leader is someone they trust.

If you can set up your dominoes correctly over a period of years, then climax in a single catastrophe, your powerful leader can act, save his country and offer salvation to other countries if they join together. A scared people with a clear path to salvation will more likely choose to sacrifice their personal freedom or national independence in order to stay safe, and if those dominoes are set up beforehand, you'll have fewer rebels and naysayers that vote against the decision to unionize. It wouldn't even have to be a long-lasting, melodramatic dystopia story either: once your powerful ruler took action and solved the problem, life would go on...maybe even better than it was before.

Answer (score 4):

**It is a condition of membership in the Federation.**

Aliens show up.  They are impressive and humanity is duly impressed.  Earth is invited to take membership in the Federation of Worlds.  But the aliens are not keen on a bunch of squabbling Earth nations jostling for a seat at the grown up table.  The aliens note that Earth nations should unite and join as one country.  They will be back after we get that sorted out.

Humanity already felt more united with other humans after seeing the aliens (of several types).  The aliens did not specify exactly how Earth nations should unite and a loose confederacy seemed to meet criteria and was palatable enough to all involved.

The seat of government of the world nation was placed in a country acceptable to all parties.  This nation gave its name to the new Earth Confederacy.

Comment: Needs a little refinement. The event (aliens show up) doesn't have any background event or even a reason why the aliens come to earth of all places. Is it the only other planet with life? (This theory is a little off since a federation is usually a group of multiple entities) Anyway, a background is needed.

Comment: @Guest2204 - My understanding is that you were looking for an event.  The rest of the world is not described in your scenario and so I figured you would describe it according to the story you wish to tell.  You are correct that federation is a group of entities.   I mention there are several types of aliens that come to Earth.  The reason Earth got invited to their party is that the aliens perceive we are smoking hot hotties, and also they noticed the nuclear bombs and radio, or maybe the warp signature of the new spaceships.    If you want to know about how people dress I got that too!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possibilities based off of the traditional victory conditions in the game series *Civilization*:

- **Scientific Victory:** Through dedication to science or even chance discovery, a scientific development that allows the increase in speed of further scientific developments is made. This discovery or invention allows the country to not only discover and develop more in a shorter period of time, but also allows the country to increase the rate at which it does so. This allows the country with control over this technology to leap ahead of the rest of the world by decades or more in terms of scientific advancement. With this advanced technology, the country can grow wealthy and dominant enough that they can simply eventually buy the other nations or they beg to join. One example of a technology that could potentially do this is a self-improving general AI.
- **Cultural Victory:** The culture of your country becomes so popular and dominant on a world stage, that people all around the world, despite not living in the country, become attracted to that countries' ethics and values, eventually using them to influence their own political systems. This could result in a scenario where while the leadership of the origin country might not directly control all the world governments, they act as an ethical and moral authority that shapes the opinions of those all around the world.
- **Domination Victory:** In military conquest, your country defeats all the other countries. On a surface level, this sounds ridiculous but Germany tried it twice, and while you'd think that in [a one-country-vs-the-world competition they'd be crushed immediately, it was actually kinda close](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXdtafGdIVM). I mean there's a lot of "what-if's" floating about concerning the decision that German leadership made in WWII, but I don't think it's too controversial of an opinion that Germany could've maintained it's hold on the "German Empire" had they not done so many drugs and drawn England, and by extension, the USA into the fight.
- **Religion Victory:** Similar to cultural domination, but probably with more centralized authority. I mean, the Catholic Church and the Pope "ruled" a significant fraction of the European continent for longer than we've had cars or sliced bread and still holds enormous political power today, so there's clearly some merit to the idea. I don't find it wildly unrealistic that a new religion or even part of an existing one could suddenly gain massive popularity and with a bit of luck and "supernatural" intervention. The right hyper-charismatic demagogue could galvanize religious fervor from all around the world, and while they might not directly end up controlling other governments, the influence achievable by religious is still enormous.
- **Diplomatic Victory:** Your country achieves "diplomatic domination" by allying with other nations and forming a world government with teeth. This would likely take a very long time, and require starting out as a nation which already has a position of dominance among its peers.

Comment: Where is secret service victory?

Comment: And economic victory?

Comment: Note that while the Pope had a lot of influence, he never did in fact rule a significant fraction of the Continent. He had the power to declare some King Emperor, but that Emperor himself was only really Emperor through military power and diplomacy. While the Pope was able to excommunicate a King if he was displeased, this (or the threat of it) did not mean he could order them around. Consider Pope Boniface VIII, who was disliked by a French King and thus simply disposed of.

Answer (score 1):

As a frame challenge, I am going to suggest that the scope of the scenario becomes so broad, as to be unanswerable. Particularly with the 'non-dystopian' criteria as the central guiding factor.

The criteria of the conditions for 'one country to absorb all other counties' to ensure any possibility of long-term stability is simply not addressed in the question, and the answer must then just hand-wave it away. Some of the issues that need to be resolved are:

**Currency**

The global country would be hard to imagine if there was not a common currency. One of the major conflicts within the EU is the Euro. One of the major backroom considerations for Brexit was the insistence of Britain to maintain its own currency, and the attempts to protect the Pound over the Euro. As the Pound and the Euro floated in value, any integration of the economies became unmanageable. Without a decision on a common currency, the EU was doomed to failure. And, as the Euro has demonstrated, this currency must be a brand new currency, not descended from any currency previously 'owned' by a particular country. Otherwise, no country will consent to its own currency and autonomy being usurped by that of another country.

**Taxes**

All states survive on taxes. Even feudal states, where the King 'owned' everything, depended on some form of taxation. But every large state has also faced the 'division of responsibility' issue. Micro-managing local issues or a 'one size fits all' system has always proven unworkable. But local issues require local sources of funding. How is the government income redistributed? Do local regions have 'powers of taxation', and how are these powers decided? A corollary to this is that distributed taxation always leads to rivalries and calls for greater local autonomy.

**Language**

As some multi-lingual countries have discovered (Canada is perhaps foremost) not having a single universal language adds a tremendous burden on a government. Everything has to go through official translation before it is enacted. Even communiques from the United Nations are delayed as they are translated into multiple languages, and each translation is vetted to maintain the original intended message against unintended consequences.

How would this global country handle this 'official language' issue?

**Justice System**

All modern justice systems with an appeals process rely on some form of 'Court of Final Judgement', a supreme court of some fashion. Appeals follow a hierarchical appeals format. Large countries can barely manage the case load expeditiously as it is, without backlogging the system up into the next century. A 'supreme court' covering the entire world would have to be humongous, and many more layers than any current system. How are the 'final decisions' made? How does the system not devolve into final decisions taking decades to be decided? And, of course, there would be so MANY of these 'final decisions' to be made in a complex society, covering the entire population and economy, that one person or 'court' would be unable to get to them all.

**Political Philosophy**

There is not, never has been, nor never will be, a universal method of 'political decision-making structure' on Earth.

As we have witnessed in the last 50 years, there is an upper limit to the size of a country that can be led by an adversarial system that changes direction every four years or so. The larger the economy, the more 'economic inertia', and no large economy can withstand the stresses of zig-zagging every four years, depending on the outcome of an election. For example, the American economy grew so large and complex, that with the zig-zag back and forth over the last two decades, the economy has completely stalled in a colossal 'economic constipation'. Basically,  the economy is self-imploding from a lack of long-term direction. Every major corporation understands that they need long-term administrative stability to run the company. They can not change CEO's and Board Chairmen every four years, and remain stable. They need a long-term consistent vision. The larger the corporation, the more crucial this long-term vision becomes. As countries become larger in population and economic complexity, it becomes more and more crucial for them to be governed by the long term, instead of the short term. Climate action comes to mind. This takes long term consistent policies and planning. Changing political philosophies every few years, after the results of an election, just will not suffice.

Yet we just do not have any conception of how such a governing system would work. The best guess scenario would be a government devoid of political parties and conflicting ideologies, vying for power in a winner-take-all system. It would have to be a co-operative single-structure system run by committees and reports, with facts and data driving the decisions.

Without solving this issue, there can be no 'universal non-dystopian global government'.

**Profit Motive**

Corporations that have devolved into the Friedman philosophy of 'short-term profit at all costs' are now folding in on themselves, with profits driven by making money on money instead of making money by making things. Now, there are so few companies actually making things, that we have a supply problem. Store shelves are bare. Corporations are making huge profits, by making fewer things and charging higher prices. The inevitable result is that there are no consumer products available to the masses, only to those who can afford them. Housing is a prime example. Developers control the supply, and to maintain ever-larger profits, they ensure there will always be a bidding war for the existing supply. A very real reason for the existing dystopian high-anxiety nature of our society.

The obvious conclusion is, that a global non-dystopian system of government has to be driven by an ideology of social responsibility and equity, not profit. Societal infrastructure has to be based on 'social benefit', not 'profit return on investment'. Otherwise, the society ends up with a few very profitable 'infrastructure corridors' for the elite with the bulk of the  population facing empty shelves. The alternative is a very dystopian society, which is specifically against the one criteria.

**Administrative complexity**

Governing the entire world and co-ordinating all facets of that government would require an unfathomably monstrous bureaucracy. I posit the only way it could be managed would be through extensive digitization and computerization. There would be layers upon layers of hierarchical management, with reports upon reports that no one person could possibly consume. Whatever system of government, it would have to be 'distributed management', which in point of fact is no longer a universal government, but a universal concept of government, a 'United Nations' on steroids, a central co-ordinating body but without any real power. An application of Dunbar's number.

**Human genetics**

Unfortunately, the reality is that the human genome is not from a universal homogenous pool. There have been at least 12 other humanoid 'species' that have contributed to the 'human' genome through cross-breeding, in various areas and populations spread over the Earth. Different inherent personalities, thinking styles, 'herd mentalities' vs 'individualist mentalities' inherited and passed down by various predecessor 'species'. Thus, we have a very diverse genome of, for instance, narcissistic, psychopathic, autistic, violent, social isolationist, non-conformist, testosterone, herd mentality, and such widely distributed over the Earth, sometimes showing up in local pools.

These differences are reflected in the various very different religions of the world. Some religions reflect a very strong hereditary 'socialist' mindset, others a very 'controlling herd mentality' hereditary mindset, others still a broad-based 'integrated with nature' hereditary mindset. It is no coincidence that these uniquely opposing religions defining different social structures are regional in their basic textual etymology (religions essentially have their ideology embedded in the language, word usage, and definitions unique to each religion) and directly map to specific areas of interbreeding between localized various pre-hominoid populations.

This is evident, today, in the rate of the Covid vaccination, with some populations splitting along extremely adversarial lines, and others more unified, the differences propagated by various mindsets and generally along predispositions towards ideological convictions or pragmatism. If the various existing countries can not within themselves internally come to grips with such an absolutely crucial issue of vaccinations against a universal threat, expecting it to happen on a global level is a stretch. For there to be a global government evolved from just one mindset, one gene pool (country), would methinks demand a universal homogenous gene pool over the entire world, with everyone 'thinking' in the same fashion, with the same personalities, and the same goals and priorities. Otherwise, one area or another, some diverse genetic population pool, would consider the global government, no matter how structured or formed, as 'dystopian' - a direct violation of the main criteria.

**TL:DR**

There is currently only one country on Earth that has a humongous population but a stable successful economy and government, that is progressing economically, technologically, and in terms of an expanding infrastructure. A country that has remained a contiguous continuous society for 8,000 years, without any border or territorial expansions. Yet even that country is still 'feeling its way' in terms of a governing structure, and will certainly not look the same as it is in 50 years. It is also evident that certain OTHER countries will absolutely NOT be 'absorbed' by that country, and thus an inevitable conflict.

Throughout all of human history, the evidence is clear. The larger and more complex the country becomes, the more unmanageable the governing of it becomes, and no empire has ever survived an expansionist agenda. The law of Diminishing Returns, with expansion inevitably resulting in negative returns, contraction, and a dystopian society.

In order to answer the question, ALL of the above factors and criteria have to be addressed, as to how they evolved into one central governing structure. There is no single factor that can address the solution. Methinks, just as the European Union, Russia, and America have discovered, a non-dystopian overly huge central government is just some impossibly mythical fantasy. No civilization has yet developed a system that covers all of the factors.